# ARM template for logic app with system assigned manage identity and API connection to keyvault , Storage blob

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager, infrastructure-as-code

I am trying to write an ARM template, it should create 3 resources:

1. logic app with system assigned manage identity.
2. API connection to read the secret from key vault.
3. API connection to upload blob storage.

I have been struggling with it for the last few hours. please assist.

It creates 3 resources if I remove parameters.$connections. if I keep those lines it gives me error

```
##[error]InvalidTemplate: The template validation failed: 'The workflow parameters '$connections' are not valid; they are not declared in the definition and therefore cannot be provided. The only declared parameters for this definition are ''.'.
```

Here is my ARM template:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "logic_app_name": {
            "defaultValue": null,
            "type": "String"
        },
        "connections_keyvault_name": {
            "defaultValue": "keyvault",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "connections_azureblob_name":{
            "defaultValue": "azureblob",
            "type": "String"            
        },
        "vaultName": {
            "defaultValue": null,
            "type": "String"
        },
        "env":{
            "defaultValue": null,
            "type": "String" 
        }        
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('connections_keyvault_name')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "kind": "V1",
            "properties": {
                "api": {
                    "id": "[concat('subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', resourceGroup().location,'/managedApis/keyvault')]"
                },
                "parameterValueSet": {
                    "name": "oauthMI",
                    "values": {
                        "vaultName": {
                            "value": "[parameters('vaultName')]"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "displayName": "[parameters('connections_keyvault_name'))]"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
            "apiVersion": "2018-07-01-preview",
            "name": "[parameters('connections_azureblob_name')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "kind": "V1",
            "properties": {
                "alternativeParameterValues":{},
                "api": {
                    "id": "[concat('subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', resourceGroup().location,'/managedApis/azureblob')]"
                },
                "customParameterValues": {},
                "displayName": "[concat(parameters('env'),'-',parameters('connections_azureblob_name'))]",
                "parameterValueSet":{
                    "name": "managedIdentityAuth",
                    "values": {}
                }
            }
        },        
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
            "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
            "name": "[parameters('logic_app_name')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "identity": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
            "tags": {
                "AppName": "cloudscape",
                "AppOwner": "Ajay Dhingra"
            },
            "properties": {
                "state": "Enabled",
                "definition": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "triggers": {},
                    "actions": {},
                    "outputs": {}
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "$connections": {
                        "value": {
                            "keyvault": {
                                "connectionId": 
                                [concat('subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', resourceGroup().name,'/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/keyvault')]"
                                "connectionName": "keyvault",
                                    "connectionProperties": {
                                        "authentication": {
                                            "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
                                        }
                                    },
                                "id": "[concat('subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', resourceGroup().location,'/managedApis/keyvault')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    ]
}
```

I expect the consumption-based logic app should use manage identity to read secrets from key vault & upload blob as well. though i read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66307261/how-to-create-api-connection-to-azure-keyvault-for-logic-app-with-managed-identi). But my problem is with parameters.$connections of logic app.

Comment: Please assist. I am unable to find an error in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have the $connection parameter defined in the parameters property of the definition.

```
"definition": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {}, <-- HERE
                    "triggers": {},
                    "actions": {},
                    "outputs": {}
                }
```

That will need to be replaced by:

```
"parameters": {
  "$connections": {
    "defaultValue": {},
    "type": "Object",
  }
},
```